# select_tag is sorting (strangely) [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a select box that looks like this (within a form_for)

```
  <%=f.select(:whatever_id, {"blah"=>0, "blah2"=>1, "blah3"=>2, "blah4"=>3}, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

and the output is good, but weird... like this:

```
<select id="personal_information_whatever_id" name="personal_information[whatever_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">blah2</option>

<option value="2">blah3</option>
<option value="0">blah</option>
<option value="3">blah4</option></select>
```

**But I want it to go in order...** what is happening, and how can I correct it?

**Edit:** I feel like the answer has to do with this

> You can never be guaranteed of any
>   order with hashes. You could try
>   .sort() to sort the values in
>   alphabetical order.

is there anything I can use aside from a hash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should use an array of arrays. The easiest way with your example would be something like this:

```
<%=f.select(:whatever_id, [["blah", 0], ["blah2", 1], ["blah3", 2], ["blah4", 3]], {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

This should suffice. Take a look at the docs at [api.rubyonrails.com](http://api.rubyonrails.com) too.

Comment: @Jon I don't know if you're kidding and I know you'll never see this since it doesn't show up in your responses, but: I hate that stupid hash syntax. I just find it so awkward to type. But it works, so...

Comment: Is there an easy way to reference the options later if you have an array of arrays?  With my hash I could do a case statement later (or something similar) and say if(value == OPTIONS[:blah2])...etc

Answer (score 2):

In your model, define your hash (in your case your model is "whatever" and your hash "blahs"):

`BLAHS = { "blah"=>0, "blah2"=>1, "blah3"=>2 }`

In the select tag where you put your hash, type

```
Whatever::BLAHS.sort {|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
```

This creates an array as described in other answers, ordered by the second item (the id/numbers).

After saving, when you pull a Whatever back out of the database and want to show the field blah, do this

```
Whatever::BLAHS.index whatever.blah
```

The array of arrays mentioned by others works, but when you want to show a Whatever, how do you show the value of blah in a nice way? I recommend sticking with the hash as it solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the options parameter is a hash, and hashes have no guaranteed order.

This should work for you

```
  <%= f.select(:whatever_id, ([["blah",0],["blah2",1],["blah3",2]]), {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

Edit in response to your comment: For collections see [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001593)

Comment: cool, thanks HermanD. I was just typing that :) Any easy workarounds in terms of collections?